DBeaver PostgreSql script variables - array
I'm looking to use a query which takes an array of known values, to be declared as a variable, but cant seem to get the syntax, or find the relevant help/documentation. Would anyone be able to offer thoughts on the following:
Running:
select unnest (array['a@b.com', 'b@c.com']);

produces a list of array items, but I'd like to replace the hardcoded list with a variable.
I've tried various permutations of things like:
@set emails = ['a@b.com', 'b@c.com'];
select :emails;
select unnest (array(:emails));

but am getting syntax errors that I cant unpick.
Would anyone be able to point out my error?...many thanks in advance

You can store the array creation, and work with it as a regular array
@set emails = ARRAY['a@b.com', 'b@c.com']
select unnest (:emails);

PS: note that there is no ; at the end of the @set statement, else it would be part of the saved variable

Excellent, thanks for that @JGH
